# PHP script looping string

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop

I have a string, I need to put this information into a database.

I'm not sure of the best way to manipulate the string to use with an insert script. my skill level is very low. I've read a bit about looping but dont know how or where to begin.

Is there a better way to manipulate the string to make db insert easier?

Many thanks

```
<?php
$date = $_SESSION['date'];
$string="UnAllocated,SUSY MCGRANAHAN,R,null,null;
UnAllocated,BERNADINE WASHER,A,null,null;
UnAllocated,DAVID KEHRER,R,null,null";
/*
I have been trying to break it down in the following way.
$new = preg_split("[;]", $string);

$x1=(explode(',', $new[1]));
$x2=(explode(',', $new[2]));

I would like to insert it into the following table
INSERT INTO table ("date, team, name, driver, car
values
('$date' ,'$x1[0]', '$x1[1]', '$x1[2]', '$x1[3]'),
('$date' ,'$x2[0]', '$x2[1]', '$x2[2]', '$x2[3]')");
*/
Table
|  date |      team     |    name   |  driver  |   car  |
---------------------------------------------------------
|  cur  |  unallocated  |  SUSY..  |     A    |   null |
|  cur  |  unallocated  |  BERN...|     R    |   null |
```

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: Is $string how your data is already formatted? The best way to ask this question is by showing us how the data you have is formatted and showing us the table you WANT to have. Then it's easy to get the data into the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to insert into your database table.

```
<?php

$string="UnAllocated,SUSY MCGRANAHAN,R,null,null;
UnAllocated,BERNADINE WASHER,A,null,null;
UnAllocated,DAVID KEHRER,R,null,null";

$arr = explode(';', $string);

foreach($arr as $row){
    $arr_row = explode(',', trim($row)); // Converting each line to array which can be used as values.
    print_r($arr_row);
    // Write your insert statement into your database.
    // e.g INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...); 
}
```

Now you can use $arr_row[0], $arr_row[1] ... and so on to build your sql.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i will give it a try and let you know how i get on :)

Comment: Thanks for the code, i have tried using it with an insert script but it is only inserting the first row and not the following.

Comment: can you show how you are inserting data into your database.

Comment: require('dbconnect.php'); //db credentials 
foreach($arr as $row){ $arr_row = explode(',', trim($row)); // Converting each line to array which can be used as values. 
// Insert data into table $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO team (date, team, name)VALUES ('$date_in', '$arr_row[0]', '$arr_row[1]')"); } 

header('Location: menu.php');`

Comment: which line getting inserted to your database? Please add semicolon at the end of your query e.g mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO team (date, team, name)VALUES ('$date_in', '$arr_row[0]', '$arr_row[1]');");

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the help, just noticed that i removed the delimiter ; from the string. works perfectly